# how can I write operating system without going deep into device drivers

Tags: c, operating-system, kernel, driver, device

I am writing operating system for educational purpose and as a maybe productive system in the future and I want to start it from scratch (I already did) and I really got upset working with hardware, writing simple VGA text mode driver was really nightmare.
the problem is that working with hardware is difficult to debug and most hardware are closed source and I am working alone (too much to cope with all available hardware alone)my operating system runs on x86 and maybe x86_64 architecture in the future so I am asking if there is way that can help avoiding working directly with hardware , something like HAL but target independent that provide a interface for communicating with wide range of available hardware 
if such thing is available It should be in C or assembly (but not C++) because I want my os to be written in pure C and assembly(for performance favor)

Comment: It is impossible and a contraction in terms. See http://osdev.org/ and maybe [GNU hurd](https://www.gnu.org/software/hurd/hurd.html).

Comment: BTW, Linux is free software, and almost all the drivers are free software too

Comment: but there is no manual explaining how to use the linux hardware devices an for some other operating system

Comment: You might glance into http://www.cs.utah.edu/flux/oskit/ (which is an abandoned project)

Comment: If you do not want to write low-level code, you really should forget about writing an OS and stick with HTML, etc. It is nonsense to start an OS with this attitude.

Comment: actually I can read and write assembly well but I want to be specific about certain modules of the operating system (which the drivers are not part of)

Comment: If you want to test scheduling algorithms and such, just take the Linux kernel or some other, working kernel and write a new scheduler for that. Modify existing code, instead of starting from scratch. A different approach would be to run the Linux kernel and some "virtual machine" on top, providing "hardware" in some idealised consistent specification to the guest kernel, which would then only need to deal with that specification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My first reaction, and judging from the comments, not just mine, was "what is left do then?". But that is actually not true.

Beside some kind of hardware abstractions into device drivers, there are other areas, to quote some items from the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating_system):

- Process management
- Interrupt handling
- Memory management
- File systems
- Networking
- Security
- other I / O
- User interface

The problem is that these need to interact with the device drivers intimately. You need a partner working on them, or try to use something existing.

E.g. if you would take a NetBSD distribution and keep mostly its device drivers, keep the boot system and cut the kernel to some minimum, I think you would still end up with something UNIX-like.

Also interesting would be a similiar cut down of some free operating system from the embedded world, e.g. like [FreeRTOS](http://www.freertos.org/).

You should also have a look at [Plan 9](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plan_9_from_Bell_Labs) which can be seen as a moderate departure from UNIX. Note however:

> Other factors that contributed to low adoption of Plan 9 include the
>   lack of commercial backup, the low number of end-user applications,
>   and the lack of device drivers.

And that was an effort by some dozen world class computer scientists.

Comment: `E.g. if you would take a NetBSD distribution and keep mostly its device drivers, keep the boot system and cut the kernel to some minimum`
I liked this, ofcourse I wont hurry and I will take my time understanding NETBSD but the question is 'is there docs or references for such thing' or some guide in case I got stuck other than long googling

Comment: You might check a copy of MINIX and the operating system book from Tanenbaum and Woodhull that describes it. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MINIX

Comment: "The Design and Implementation of the FreeBSD Operating System" by McKusick and Neville-Neil is a recent book on the FreeBSD kernel.

Answer (score 1):

From Wikipedia,

> An operating system (OS) is system software that manages computer hardware and software resources and provides common services for computer programs.

The whole point of the OS is to provide an interface to the hardware, so no, you can't escape dealing with the hardware if you are writing an OS.

Comment: as you said `hardware and software resources`  I want some readily available hardware manager that can help me building process manager and testing new scheduling algorithms and testing say loaders and all that stuff (with out worrying about hardware)

Comment: Again, you are inconsistent. A kernel scheduler is dealing or related to the hardware (e.g. interrupts, caches).

Comment: Re "I want some readily available hardware manage", Again, the OS is that hardware manager. Why do say you want to write an OS if you want to use someone else's OS?

Comment: yes the hardware of the processor which is well documented but not 3rd party hardware (xyz mouse and xyz monitor and xyz keyboard which I should figure out how to drive)

Comment: XYZ mouse & keyboard are USB these days. And monitors are HDMI. Both are well documented protocols.

Comment: You don't need to support specific peripherals. Your OS could support drivers.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this if and only if the other take this part i.e they do it for your OS ,if your OS present a brilliant idea or any way it be attractive for developers or companies, the driver is not your problem, and if your OS is not attractive, the driver is dead problem.